# The Deep Learning Book considers the empirical distribution $\hat p_{data}$ a function only of the data-generating process, what does that mean?

Tags: machine-learning

[Chapter 5.5 (Page 130) of the Deep Learning Book](https://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/ml.html) gives formula (5.61)

[image]

for training machine learning models.

where $p_{model}(\mathbf x)$ is a parametric family of probability distributions over the same space indexed by $\mathbf{\theta}$

and $\hat p_{data}$ denotes the empirical distribution.

I'm conscious that the true probability $p_{data}(\mathbf x)$ is usually unknown in practice though, to make the question concrete and easy to understand, consider this true data-generating distribution

$x \sim \mathcal{N}_{true}(x; \mu, \sigma^2, \epsilon), \ where\  \mu=1, \sigma=0.5 \tag{1}$

and $\epsilon$ is drawn from another normal distribution with a mean of zero and standard deviation of 0.01.

let $
\mathbb D = \{x^{(1)}, \cdots, x^{(m)}\}
$ denotes the set of m=30 training examples drawn independently from formula (1).

This Python code is to simulate the data generation

```
# m denotes the number of training examples
m_examples = 30
np.random.seed(0)
noises = np.random.normal(0, .01, m_examples)
D_dataset = np.random.normal(1, .5, m_examples) + noises
```

and, here are the training examples in $\mathbb D$

```
array([1.09511424, 1.19308283, 0.56589451, 0.0320107 , 0.84471951,
       1.06840171, 1.62464622, 1.59967635, 0.8053044 , 0.85295461,
       0.47716395, 0.30453377, 0.15447528, 1.97660445, 0.74961254,
       0.78429959, 0.38854311, 1.3866936 , 0.19618175, 0.8850889 ,
       0.52673682, 1.19998743, 0.75324179, 0.40226226, 1.00860643,
       1.19962228, 1.0337162 , 1.14936411, 0.69816675, 0.833323  ])
```

the arithmetic mean

```
>>> np.mean(D_dataset)
0.8596676363956413
```

the standard deviation

```
>>> np.sqrt(np.var(D_dataset))
0.44725697845961726
```

Given that, is the distribution

$x \sim \mathcal{N}_{true}(x; \mu, \sigma^2), \ where\  \mu=0.85966, \sigma=0.44726 \tag{2}$

the empirical distribution $\hat p_{data}$, the estimator p_{model} or something else?

The part of the book cited above considers $\hat p_{data}$ a function only of the data-generating process, what does that mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\model}{p_{\text{model}}}\newcommand{\emp}{\hat p_\text{data}}$The empirical distribution is a discrete distribution that puts a mass of $1/n$ on each realized data point (if there are no ties; if $x_i$ appears $m$ times then its mass will be $m/n$). $\emp$ does not depend on the model at all. The data generating process completely determines what $\emp$ will be. For example, if we have $X_1, \dots, X_n \stackrel{\text{iid}}\sim \mathcal N(\mu_0, 1)$, then that already completely determines the behavior of $\emp$. It doesn't matter how we're modeling this or what our estimate of $\mu_0$ is.

It might help to write out $\emp$ more fully as
$$
\emp(x) = \frac 1n \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbf 1_{X_i = x}
$$
so we can see that $\emp$ is a random variable itself (technically it is a Radon-Nikodym derivative of a random measure) and its distribution is completely induced by the distribution of the $X_i$. $\emp$ *does* depend on $\mu_0$, the true parameter, since that's what specifies the particular data generating process of $\mathcal N(\mu_0, 1)$, but our model does not affect this and $\mu_0$ is also constant here.

And $\text E_{\emp}[\log \emp(x)]$ is even easier: this is the negative entropy of a discrete uniform distribution over $\{x_1, \dots, x_n\}$ so we have
$$
\text E_{\emp}[\log \emp(x)] = \frac 1n \sum_{i=1}^n \log \emp(x_i) = \frac 1n \sum_i \log\left(\frac 1n\right) = -\log n.
$$

That's why, from the perspective of fitting $\model$, $\text E_{\emp}[\log \emp(x)]$ is constant since it does not vary with the model parameters $\theta$.

Comment: Your answer is quit understandable. Thank you so much! Does $\mathcal N(\mu_0, 1)$ means the standard deviation of the normal distribution $\sigma=1$, is a known quantity in this example? Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @soplus2018 hey, yeah, that's correct. The variance parameter wasn't important for my example so I just fixed it at a known value of $1$.